# IDLE automatically squeezes large amount of lines

Tags: python, printing, python-idle

I've been working on a **chatbot** in **IDLE** using **python**. On my laptop everything works **fine** but on my desktop **IDLE** automatically **squeezes** the text ‍♂️

[This is what it looks like in **IDLE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqW6Y.png).

The text that's being squeezed are just **empty lines**. I've **embedded** the code I used to print out the empty lines **below**...

`print("\n" * 150)`

Does anyone know **how** to disable it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a new feature, still being refined.  To disable, go to Options => Configure IDLE => General tab => Shell preferences => Auto-Squeeze min lines [50] and change 50 to a large count.

Double click the label to expand in place.  Right click for other options.

Comment: Would be nice to disable with `-1` instead of entering large count. I don't like this feature, personal opinion.

Comment: @Jarad Entering `-1` results in squeezing every single line of text.

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat your blank lines in a quantity that is less than the squeeze threshold.

```
print("\n"*25)
print("\n"*25)
print("\n"*25)
print("\n"*25)
print("\n"*25)
print("\n"*25)

# OR

i = 0
while i < 6:
    print("\n"*25)
    i = i + 1
```